# Check if it's 'today' in another timezone

Tags: javascript, unix, unix-timestamp

Given any UNIX timestamp, either created just minutes ago or multiple hours, how would I check if that UNIX falls on today's date in x timezone.
For example, I get a UNIX timestamp from a database, how would I check if that's today in say EST time?

I've tried changing timezone's with UNIX but I couldn't figure out how only with a Date object but I think there'd be an easier way than changing UNIX to a Date object then checking them against each other then changing to UNIX again.

Removing the difference in time from the UNIX timestamp then checking if it's today's date, although I think this would work I haven't yet figured out how I would write out the logic to this.

I'd really appreciate any help or explanation!
- Timjime

Comment: Check if the UNIX I've provided is on today's date in x timezone (This was an answer to a user who removed his comment)

Comment: What do you mean? It's always "today" no matter where you are?

Comment: I understand but given any UNIX value, that could be the current one or one of 2 weeks ago, is that UNIX today in x timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the unix timestamp for the start and end of "today", then check to see if the provided timestamp is between them.

```js
let todayStart = new Date()
todayStart.setHours(0,0,0,0)

const todayEnd = new Date()
todayEnd.setHours(0,0,0,0)
todayEnd.setDate(todayEnd.getDate()+1)

const todayStartUnix = Math.floor(todayStart / 1000)
const todayEndUnix = Math.floor(todayEnd / 1000)

let unixTest = 12345678
console.log(unixTest > todayStartUnix && unixTest < todayEndUnix)

unixTest = Date.now() / 1000
console.log(unixTest > todayStartUnix && unixTest < todayEndUnix)
```